# What is the best way to prepend a conjunction to the end of an imploded array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, list

Let's say I have an array.

```
$shopping_list = array('eggs', 'butter', 'milk', 'cereal');
```

What is the easiest and/or most clever way to display this as a comma-delimited list and prepend a word (conjunction, preposition, etc.) to the last value?  Desired results include:

```
'eggs, butter, milk, and cereal'
'eggs, butter, milk, or cereal'
'eggs, butter, milk, with cereal'
'eggs, butter, milk, in cereal'
// etc.
```

The array will be of variable length, may be associative, and preferably it shouldn't be modified.  It needn't be imploded either; I figure this is just the standard way of doing things like this.  Array dereferencing is fine too, but something PHP 5.3-compatible would be great.

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
$extra_word = 'and';

implode(', ', array_slice($shopping_list, 0, count($shopping_list) - 1)) 
    . ', ' . $extra_word . ' '
    . implode(',', array_slice($shopping_list, count($shopping_list) - 1));
```

But that's a doozy.  Loops are cleaner and slightly less inept:

```
$i = 0;
$output = '';

foreach ($shopping_list as $item) {
   $i += 1;
   if ($i > 1) {
       $output .= ', ';
       if ($i === count($shopping_list)) {
           $output .= $extra_word . ' ';
       }
   }

   $output .= $item;
}
```

Both of these ways seem roundabout.  Is there a better way out there that comes to mind?

Comment: That's not a standard thing to do and you already offered two solutions. This is not a question.

Comment: @markus What is 'that'?  String manipulation?  I do my grocery shopping list in PHP.  It helps a lot :)

Comment: @Voitcus I'm just using a counter in case the array is associative.

Comment: @danronmoon yes, I realized this and removed the comment (for future reference it was to use `foreach($array as $i=>$item)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is cleaner too.

```
$pop = array_pop($shopping_list);
echo implode(", ", $shopping_list)." and $pop.";
```

Comment: Ah I'm liking this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Some idea might be with copying the array.

```
 $array = array_values($shopping_list);
 $array[count($array)-1] = $extraword . ' ' . $array[count($array)-1];
 // implode etc.
```

The Starx solution is better.

Comment: I like the sound of `The Starx Solution` :) (+1)

Comment: Now I'm thinking this might not work if the array is associative.

Comment: It might help to set `$array` to `array_values($shopping_list)` in case array is associative.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$last = count($shopping_list)-1 ;
$shopping_list[$last] = "in {$shopping_list[$last]} ;
```